# Skipped errored rows in bulk insert

Tags: sql-server, error-handling, bulkinsert

Is there a way to do a bulk insert in Sql Server where rows with errors are skipped rather than the whole process failing?  I don't mean just keeping those rows inserted prior to the error; I mean inserting all rows that aren't errored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use SSIS, you can redirect the Error Output of the Destination to a garbage Script Component or a flat file. I often do that so I can then examine the rows that went awry.

Additionally, if you're using [`BULK INSERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx), then you can use the `MAX_ERRORS` (setting it to a very high value) and `ERROR_FILE` parameters to specify how to handle errors effectively.